# Combine two NSMutableDictionarys with same key

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to combine two NSMutableDictionarys, but the issue I am running into is when I add them it just overwrites the other. For example Dictionary A has the following Data:

```
{
    StationLogs = (
                {
            log = "This is the Log Text";
            timeStamp = "2014-01-04 04:31:04 +0000";
            title = Title;
        }
    );
}
```

And Dictionary 2 would have this data:

```
{
        StationLogs = (
        {
            log = "logText";
            timeStamp = "2014-01-04 04:35:04 +0000";
            title = Title2;
        }
    );
}
```

How would I get them to merge to look something like this:

```
    {
        StationLogs = (
        {
            log = "This is the Log Text";
            timeStamp = "2014-01-04 04:31:04 +0000";
            title = Title;
        },
        {
            log = "logText";
            timeStamp = "2014-01-04 04:35:04 +0000";
            title = Title2;
        }
    );
}
```

I have searched on stack overflow and on the rest of the web, but could not find anything. I am sorry if this was already answered and I could not find it because I was not searching for the correct phrase.

Thanks,
Skylar

Comment: Just use a different key for each value. Using a dictionary is fundamental - you should read a programming book, or even just apple's objective-c and class reference documentation, because you would have a lot of problems if you try writing code without any kind of foundation.

Comment: you cant add  data already avalible in dict with same key.If you want achive it take a dictnry and add array for key StationLogs and now you add dictnar to arry which is contaning data you will get as same you r aspecting

Comment: The reason I am not using the same key is I need to be able to add data to the same set to get multiple messages, the program connects about 35 workstations and each of them has their own datasets, when they submit data, I want to add it to the archives and the best way to do that is to keep them separate and not just throw them all in. I could be wrong, but in my situation that is how the rest of the program is already written.

Comment: hey its not need to store with diffrent key if want do it .it is not a big deal or work it small work but you have to work arround little to get it or achive above req using array ok wait i will send u some code which make you how to achive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each data set and create your merged data set

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1; //Your first set of data
    NSMutableDictionary *dict2; //Your second set of data

    NSArray *keys1 = [dict1 allKeys];
    NSArray *keys2 = [dict2 allKeys];

    NSMutableDictionary *combinedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    //Iterating through first data set
    for (id key in keys1) {
        NSArray *array = [dict1 objectForKey:key];

        NSMutableArray *subArray = [combinedDictionary objectForKey:key];
        if (!subArray) {
            subArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [combinedDictionary setObject:subArray forKey:key];
        }

        [subArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    }

    //Iterating through second data set
    for (id key in keys2) {
        NSArray *array = [dict2 objectForKey:key];

        NSMutableArray *subArray = [combinedDictionary objectForKey:key];
        if (!subArray) {
            subArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            [combinedDictionary setObject:subArray forKey:key];
        }

        [subArray addObjectsFromArray:array];
    }
```

Instead of creating a new `NSMutableDictionary` as `combinedDictionary`, you can replace merged data in one of the `NSMutableDictionary` you already have.

Comment: @OstlerDev Is that wat you need?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is basically a set of key-value pairs. Your Dictionary A and Dictionary 2 illustrate this. But in your combined "dictionary" what you have is a set of two dictionaries, not a set of key-value pairs. In other words it is just not possible to combine dictionaries like that because the result that you are expecting is not a dictionary. If you want a set of dictionaries, use `NSSet` or `NSArray`(recommended)

Answer (score 0):

may this help you ...

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"This is the Log Text",@"log",@"2014-01-04 04:31:04 +0000",@"timeStamp",@"Title",@"title", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Log Text",@"log",@"2014-01-04 04:35:04 +0000",@"timeStamp",@"Title2",@"title", nil];

NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict];
NSArray *arr1=[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict1];

//here is your first dictnary
NSMutableDictionary *dictm1=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arr,@"StationLogs", nil];


NSLog(@"%@",dictm1);

 //here is your second dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *dictm2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:arr1,@"StationLogs", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dictm2);

//now here you get array of dictnary which is storted with key value "StationLogs" for first didtnary
NSArray *tempArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dictm1 objectForKey:@"StationLogs"]];
NSLog(@"%@",tempArray);

  //now here you get array of dictnary whaich is storted with key value "StationLogs" for second didtnary
NSMutableArray *tempArray1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[dictm2 objectForKey:@"StationLogs"]] ;

[tempArray1 addObjectsFromArray:tempArray];

//now adding value of second dictionary to first dict
[dictm1 setValue:tempArray1 forKey:@"StationLogs"];

NSLog(@"%@",dictm1);
```

and i had made simple if you can make it comact
Like coding